# How to make a JButton start a loop

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a timer programming that adds one to a variable then outputs it to a JTextField every second. However, I can't seem to get the button to start the timer and keep it going. It always adds one, but then quits. How do I make it so that whenever I press the start button, the timer starts counting until I hit stop?

```
// creates timer
private Timer count;


public static void main (String[] args) {
    //inits new timer and GUI
    timer frame = new timer();
    frame.setSize(400,150);
    frame.createGUI();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

//adds start to window
start = new JButton("Start Timer");
    window.add(start);
    start.addActionListener(this);

//actionPerformed class
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {


    if(event.getSource() == start) {
        min1.setText(Integer.toString(time / 60));
        sec1.setText(Integer.toString(time % 60));
        time++;
        }
    else {
        time++;
    }
```

I'm new to stackoverflow, so please exscuse any incorrect formattings

Comment: Are you using a Swing `Timer`? If not, then you should

Comment: So forget about the Stop button. First just create your Start button that starts the timer and increments 1 every time the timer fires. Then once you get that working you add the Stop button. Right now you don't know if the problem is with your Start button or the Stop logic you added. Simplify the problem and solve one problem at a time. If you need more help then post a proper [mcve] with just your Start button the demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I don't know if this is better, but I hope it is!

Comment: How is that a complete example? How does the code compile? Where is your Timer logic?. All you do is add an ActionListener to the button. You also need an ActionListener for the Timer. So all the code in button ActionListener does is start the Timer. Then the ActionListener for the Timer increments the time. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to use Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for an example. Or search the web/form for examples using the Timer class.

Comment: Here is a basic example of a Timer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291429/jlabel-showing-both-old-and-new-numbers/36291516#36291516. The Timer is started automatically. So you need to modify the code to have a button create and start the Timer.

Comment: I am confused. If I add an ActionListener for the Timer, what would that do? I just learned about Timer a few days ago and I'm still sorting through what ActionListener does, but I have been reading up on it, so I apologize for my ignorance. In addition, I understand how to create the timer, I'm more confused on the swing side of things.

Comment: (1-) Did you read the tutorial? Did you look at my example and download and execute the code???

Comment: Yes, I still don't understand how to link the JButton actionListener with the Timer and google isn't really helping.

Comment: I'm sorry there is no way you could have read the tutorial and then downloaded and test my example code in 6 minutes which is all the time to you took to respond to my links I provide. `I still don't understand how to link the JButton actionListener with the Timer` - I just told you: `So you need to modify the code to have a button create and start the Timer`. So where is your `MCVE` that shows the changes you tried to make to my example code???

Comment: O I think I got it now, I was thinking that I had to write my code in the ActionPerformed, but I have to do it in ActionListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code in which timer is start by button and also stop by button.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Example implements ActionListener {
    Timer timer;
    int count=0;
    JButton startButton;
    JButton stopButton;
    JLabel countLabel;
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel contentPane;

    public Example() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(this);

        stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
        stopButton.addActionListener(this);

        countLabel = new JLabel("0");

        contentPane.add(startButton);
        contentPane.add(countLabel);
        contentPane.add(stopButton);

        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            count++;
                countLabel.setText(count+"");
                    }
                };
        timer = new Timer(100,listener);
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == startButton) {
            timer.start();
        }
        if(e.getSource() == stopButton) {
            timer.stop();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Example();
    }
}
```