# Delay between multiple setText java

Tags: java, swing, delay, freeze

I want to put a delay between every if in this for
I've triend with Thread.sleep() but this freezes the gui and I don't know is it viable to use multiple swing timers in a loop.
[image]

Here I'm trying with a swing timer and keeps freezing the gui, what I'm doing wrong?.

```
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      int i=0;
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

          try
          {
                System.out.print(solucion.get(i)+" "+solucion.get(i+1)+" "+solucion.get(i+2)+" \n"+solucion.get(i+3)+" "+solucion.get(i+4)+" "+solucion.get(i+5)+" \n"+solucion.get(i+6)+" "+solucion.get(i+7)+" "+solucion.get(i+8));
                System.out.println("\n");

                Btn1.setText(solucion.get(i));
                Btn2.setText(solucion.get(i+1));
                Btn3.setText(solucion.get(i+2));
                Btn4.setText(solucion.get(i+3));
                Btn5.setText(solucion.get(i+4));
                Btn6.setText(solucion.get(i+5));
                Btn7.setText(solucion.get(i+6));
                Btn8.setText(solucion.get(i+7));
                Btn9.setText(solucion.get(i+8));


                i++;
          }
          catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();} //if it gets a error we are at the end of the list and stop the timer

      }
  };
  new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Swing Timer`. The Timer replaces the loop.

Every time the Timer fires you set the text and then increment the value of "i". When "i" reaches a specific value you stop the Timer.

See: [Jlabel showing both old and new numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291429/jlabel-showing-both-old-and-new-numbers/36291516#36291516) for a simple example to get you started.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information.

Comment: I've tried with a swing timer (I posted the code in the question) but it keeps freezing the gui

Comment: Forget it, the problem was the list "solucion" didn't have the values I needed.
The swing Timer works perfectly thanks.

Comment: @JuanErroa 1) you don't have 9 setText(...) statement in the ActionListner. You only need one statement for the current value to set based on the index 2) You don't use an IndexOutOfBounds Exception to stop the loop, use the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the guid not to freeze you need to execute it in a different thread. Running it in the main thread will aways cause the guid to freeze. You are using swing so the way to go would be:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          // put your statements and delay here
      }
  });
```